# How to populate Kendo Upload with previously uploaded files

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using the Kendo UI File Upload for MVC and it works great. On my edit page, I want to show the files that were previously uploaded from the Create page. For visual consistency, I would like to re-use the upload widget on my edit page so the user can use the "remove" functionality, or add additional files if they choose. Does the upload widget support this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

So, I realize this is question pretty old, but I recently figured out how to do this reliably. While the other answer on here will certainly display the files, it doesn't really wire it up to any of the events (specifically the "remove" event). Also, rather than manually setting all of this up, I figured I'd much rather have Kendo do all of the real dirty work.

Note, this only applies if your file upload is not set to autosync. If you use the auto upload feature, you can find examples in the Kendo documentation here: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/upload#configuration-files

So anyway, let's assume we have a file input that we've made into a Kendo Upload:

```html
<input id="files" name="files" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var $upload = $("#files");
    var allowMultiple = Boolean($upload.attr("multiple"));

    $upload.kendoUpload({
        multiple: allowMultiple,
        showFileList: true,
        autoUpload: false        
    });
}
```

Then, we just need to get the information about the files to our jQuery. I like to jam it into JSON strings in hidden fields, but you can do it however you want.

Here's an example using the Mvc HtmlHelpers and Newtonsoft's JSON.NET (I don't use Razor, but you should get the general idea):

```cs
if (Model.Attachments.Count > 0)
{
    var files = Model.Attachments.Select(x => new { name = x.FileName, extension = x.FileExtension, size = x.Size });
    var filesJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(files);
    Html.Render(Html.Hidden("existing-files", filesJson));
}
```

Note, the format there is *incredibly important*. We're tying to match the structure of the JavaScript object that Kendo is expecting:

```js
{
    relatedInput : sourceInput,
    fileNames: [{ // <-- this is the collection we just built above            
        name: "example.txt",
        extenstion: ".txt",            
        size: 1234
    }]
}
```

So, then all that's left to do is put it all together. Basically, we're going to recreate the `onSelect` function from Kendo's internal `syncUploadModule`:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // setup the kendo upload
    var $upload = $("#files");
    var allowMultiple = Boolean($upload.attr("multiple"));

    var upload = $upload.kendoUpload({
        multiple: allowMultiple,
        showFileList: true,
        autoUpload: false        
    }).getKendoUpload();

    // initialize the files
    if (upload) {
        var filesJson = $("[name$='existing-files']").val();
        if (filesJson) {                
            var files = JSON.parse(filesJson);

            var name = $.map(files, function (item) {
                return item.name;
            }).join(", ");

            var sourceInput = upload._module.element.find("input[type='file']").last();
            upload._addInput(sourceInput.clone().val(""));
            var file = upload._enqueueFile(name, {
                relatedInput : sourceInput,
                fileNames : files
            });
            upload._fileAction(file, "remove");
        }
    }
});
```

And that's pretty much it!

Comment: hello,thank you for your good answer. please help. how can I show init files on green theme like kendo async? (.k-file-success)

Comment: @valverij Any idea how we can achieve this inside kendo grid in edit mode?

Comment: @minamorsali if you want to do that, you need add files one by one,  replace `var file = upload._enqueueFile(name, {
                relatedInput : sourceInput,
                fileNames : files
            });
            upload._fileAction(file, "remove");` with a for loop. Sommeting similar with this:

Comment: @minamorsali Sommeting similar with this: `for (var i = 0; i < filesJson.lenght; i++) {
                var file = upload._enqueueFile("", { relatedInput: sourceInput, fileNames: [filesJson[i]] });
                file.addClass("k-file-success").data("files", [filesJson[i]]);
                upload._fileState(file, "uploaded");
                upload._fileAction(file, "remove");
            }`

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a way to do this.

Basically, you need HTML that mimics what the Upload control generates, and you use a bit of JavaScript to hook each item up. I initially render the HTML as hidden, then after you initialize the Kendo Upload control, you append the HTML list to the parent container that Kendo creates.

This is my MVC view:

```Razor
@if (Model.Attachments != null && Model.Attachments.Count > 0)
{
  <ul id="existing-files" class="k-upload-files k-reset" style="display: none;">
    @foreach (var file in Model.Attachments)
    {
      <li class="k-file" data-att-id="@file.Id">
        <span class="k-icon k-success">uploaded</span>
        <span class="k-filename" title="@file.Name">@file.Name</span>
        <button type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-upload-action">
          <span class="k-icon k-delete"></span>
          Remove
        </button>
      </li>
    }
  </ul>
}
```

and here is the JavaScript (note, it was generated from CoffeeScript):

```js
var $fileList, $files, item, _fn, _i, _len;
$fileList = $("#existing-files");
if ($fileList.length > 0) {
  $(".k-upload").append($fileList);
  $files = $(".k-file");
  _fn = function(item) {
    var $item, fileId, filenames;
    $item = $(item);
    fileId = $item.data("att-id");
    filenames = [
      {
        name: fileId
      }
    ];
    return $item.data("fileNames", filenames);
  };
  for (_i = 0, _len = $files.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    item = $files[_i];
    _fn(item);
  }
  $fileList.show();
}
```

You can find the [full write up on my blog](http://bit.ly/15LhuD3) where I go into depth on the topic. I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that! Thanks for removing it.

Comment: @dwhite Any idea how we can achieve this inside kendo grid in edit mode?

Answer (score 1):

Some additional searches gave me the answer I *wasn't* looking for - According to [this](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/upload/adding-files-to-populate-on-initialization.aspx) and [this](http://www.kendoui.com//forums/ui/upload/file-list-templates.aspx), Telerik does not support pre-populating an upload widget with previously uploaded documents.

Answer (score 1):

It has been added in the options since this question has been asked.

Check out http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/upload#configuration-files

It only works in async mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
            @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
              .Name("files")
              .Async(a => a
                  .Save("SaveFile", "Home")
                  .Remove("RemoveFile", "Home")
                  .AutoUpload(true))
              .Files(files =>
              {
                  foreach (var file in Model.FundRequest.Files)
                  {
                          files.Add().Name(file.Name).Extension(Path.GetExtension(file.Name)).Size((long)file.SizeKb * 1024);
                   }

              }))
```

My Model has a reference to my "FundRequest" object that has a List of "File" objects, so I just loop through each "File" and add.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out!

```js
<script>
    var files = [
        { name: "file1.doc", size: 525, extension: ".doc" },
        { name: "file2.jpg", size: 600, extension: ".jpg" },
        { name: "file3.xls", size: 720, extension: ".xls" },
    ];

    $("#upload").kendoUpload({
        async: {
            saveUrl: "Home/Save",
            removeUrl: "Home/Remove",
            autoUpload: true
        },
        files: files
    });
</script>
```

```html
<input type="file" name="files" id="upload" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this out, this is it.

Below code is copied and adapted from [kendo-ui documentation](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/upload/initialfiles):

```html
<div id="example">
    <div>
        <div class="demo-section">
            <input name="files" id="files" type="file" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (sessionStorage.initialFiles === undefined) {
                sessionStorage.initialFiles = "[]";
            }

            var initialFiles = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.initialFiles);

            $("#files").kendoUpload({
                showFileList: true,
                multiple: true,
                async: {
                    saveUrl: "save",
                    autoUpload: false,
                    batch: true
                },
                files: initialFiles,
                success: onSuccess
            });

            function onSuccess(e) {
                var currentInitialFiles = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.initialFiles);
                for (var i = 0; i < e.files.length; i++) {
                    var current = {
                        name: e.files[i].name,
                        extension: e.files[i].extension,
                        size: e.files[i].size
                    }

                    if (e.operation == "upload") {
                        currentInitialFiles.push(current);
                    } else {
                        var indexOfFile = currentInitialFiles.indexOf(current);
                        currentInitialFiles.splice(indexOfFile, 1);
                    }
                }
                sessionStorage.initialFiles = JSON.stringify(currentInitialFiles);
            }
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Please remember that posts on Stack Overflow are supposed to be *your original work*, not just a copy paste from an external resource. You can quote code from external sources [with proper referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), and ideally add some explanation written by you about how that works, to make it passable for fair use.